# WDSL Webservice to manage Exchange Server

Tags: c#, php, web-services, exchange-server

I have created a web service that should allow to pass commands to the Exchange Server Powershell. When I test it by running it on the machine with VS (localhost) everything works. However, when I try to use this service from a other machine. I get Access Denied Error.

This is the service:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Remoting;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace pshell
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://some1.domain.int/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class PowerShellService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        private bool Authenticate(string u, string p)
        {
            if ((u == "xxxxxx") && (p == "xxxxxxx"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private int SecurityLevel(string u)
        {
            if (u == "xxxxx")
                return 100;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string PSCmd(string authuser, string authpass, string cmd, string pars)
        {

            if (!Authenticate(authuser, authpass))
                return "<collection><RESULT status=\"ERROR\" message=\"Authentication failed!\" /></collection>";

            String Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UUPASS"];

            System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password)
                secureString.AppendChar(c);

            PSCredential ExchangeCredential = new PSCredential(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UUNAME"], secureString);

            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UURI"]), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", ExchangeCredential);

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

            PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

            if (cmd.Trim() != "")
            {
                //here we check for security level
                if (SecurityLevel(authuser) >= 100)
                {
                    //admin fully allowed
                    command.AddCommand(cmd);
                }
                else
                {
                    //test for allowed commands
                    if ((SecurityLevel(authuser) < 100) &&
                        (SecurityLevel(authuser) >= 90))
                    {
                        if (cmd.ToLower() == "get-mailbox")
                        {
                            command.AddCommand(cmd);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                return "<collection><RESULT status=\"ERROR\" message=\"Missing command!\" /></collection>";

            if (pars.Trim() != "")
            {
                string[] parameters = pars.Split('|');
                foreach (string item in parameters)
                {
                    String p = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf("="));
                    String v = item.Substring(item.IndexOf("=") + 1);
                    if (p.Trim().ToLower() == "password")
                    {
                        System.Security.SecureString passString = new System.Security.SecureString();
                        foreach (char c in v)
                            passString.AppendChar(c);
                        command.AddParameter(p, passString);

                    }
                    else if ((v.Trim().ToLower() == "false") ||
                             (v.Trim().ToLower() == "true"))
                    {
                        if (v.Trim().ToLower() == "false")
                            command.AddParameter(p, false);
                        else
                            command.AddParameter(p, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        command.AddParameter(p, v);
                    }
                }
            }
            powershell.Commands = command;

            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pl = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;

            Collection<PSObject> results = null;

            string xml = "<collection>";

            try
            {
                results = powershell.Invoke();
                var error = pl.Error.Read() as Collection<ErrorRecord>;
                if (error != null)
                {
                    foreach (ErrorRecord er in error)
                    {
                        xml += "<RESULT status=\"ERROR\" type=\"pipe\" message=\"" + er.ErrorDetails.Message + "\" />";
                    }
                    pl.Stop();
                }
                xml += "<RESULT status=\"OK\" />";
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                xml += "<RESULT status=\"ERROR\" type=\"exception\" codelevel=\"1\" message=\"" + err.Message + "\" />";
            }

            try
            {
                foreach (PSObject item in results)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Properties.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (item.Properties.ElementAt(i).MemberType == PSMemberTypes.Property)
                        {
                            xml += "<" + item.Properties.ElementAt(i).Name + ">" +
                                   item.Properties.ElementAt(i).Value +
                                   "</" + item.Properties.ElementAt(i).Name + ">";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                xml += "<RESULT status=\"ERROR\" type=\"exception\" codelevel=\"2\" message=\"" + err.Message + "\" />";
            }

            xml += "</collection>";

            return xml;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the PHP code that I want to use to send a command:

```
$ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

$params = array('authuser' => 'xxxx', 
                'authpass' => 'xxxx', 
                'cmd' => 'get-mailbox', 
                'pars' => '');

$client = new SoapClient("http://web.domain.com/pshell/callpshell.asmx?WSDL", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$response = $client->PSCmd($params)->PSCmdResult;

print $response;
```

and this is the error message I receive:

Connecting to remote server some1.domain.int failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have enabled Remote Access on the Exchange Server, and I did everything Remote Troubleshooting suggested.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Access Denied Error occurs because the web service is launched as IIS_USER which has insufficient rights to call remote powershell.

OK after long poking around, I resolved the issue like this:

1. Create a new Applciation Pool
2. Set the Identity of the application pool to the user that has the rights to access Powershell remotely
3. Bind the WebService to the Application pool

and it works :)